# Why isn't this filter outputting IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to automatically embed youtube videos for user generated content.  My filter looks for links in general and then tests them to see if they are valid YouTube videos.  If they are, it should embed the video with the standard iframe code.  If not, it's just a link.  However, the filter isn't outputting the iframe code at all.  I'm assuming this has something to prevent cross-site scripting attacks, but I have no idea how I can get around it.

```
function ytVidId(url) {
  var p = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
  return (url.match(p)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
}

myapp.filter('parseUrls', function() {
    //with protocol
    var urlPattern = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/gi;
    return function(text, target, otherProp) {        
        if (text == null) {
            return "";
        }
        angular.forEach(text.match(urlPattern), function(url) {
            if(ytVidId(url)){
                text = text.replace(url, '<div class="video-container"><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+ ytVidId(url) +'" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe></div>');
            }else{
                text = text.replace(url, '<a target="' + target + '" href='+ url + '>' + url + '</a>');
            }

        });
        return text;        
    };
})
```

In use:

```
<span ng-bind-html="p.body | noHTML | newlines | parseUrls:'_blank'"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular requires you to pass HTML though the 'sce' (Strict Contextual Escaping) provider.

[Documentation on the SCE provider here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce)

So it would look something like this (untested but in theory it should)

```
function ytVidId(url) {
  var p = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
  return (url.match(p)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
}    

myapp.filter('parseUrls', ['$sce', function() {
    //with protocol
    var urlPattern = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/gi;
    return function(text, target, otherProp) {        
        if (text == null) {
            return "";
        }
        angular.forEach(text.match(urlPattern), function(url) {
            if(ytVidId(url)){
                text = text.replace(url, $sce.trustAs('html', '<div class="video-container"><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+ ytVidId(url) +'" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe></div>'));
            }else{
                text = text.replace(url, $sce.trustAs('html', '<a target="' + target + '" href='+ url + '>' + url + '</a>'));
            }    

        });
        return text;        
    };
}])`
```

Comment: This was pretty close.  I actually found that piping in this filter worked...

.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
        return function(val) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
        };
    })